# Adding Outgoing Caller Id MVC ASP.NET

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In the following [document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids) the twilio Rest API claims to expose the ability to create new outgoing caller Ids. When I try to access the OutgoingCallerIdResource exposed in the Rest API I do not have an option to create a new Caller Id. Any help would be appreciated. The actual problem I am trying to solve is the ability to add verified numbers to twilio without having to use the console every time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can kick off a [new verification that adds a verified number to your account using the Outbound Caller ID resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list-post) by making a `POST` request to the list resource.

Doing that in C# would look a bit like this:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
        const string authToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("PHONE_NUMBER_TO_BE_VERIFIED");
        var validationRequest = ValidationRequestResource.Create(
            phoneNumber,
            friendlyName: "My Home Phone Number");

        Console.WriteLine(validationRequest.ValidationCode);
    }
}
```

[Check out the documentation and example code here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list-post).

Comment: quick question is TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken) the same as the init and should this be exposed as a singleton in a startup config?

Comment: It is the same, yes, and you should expose that as a singleton, yes.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: It's not a problem. Hope the rest of your app is going well :)

Comment: Hi, may you please assist in the regard, as this only creates a validation request object. What next after getting the code?

Comment: You need to display the code to the user somehow so that they can enter the code as part of the phone call. When the user enters the code successfully their number is verified.